# puppet: trying to use definition $title as part of a hiera variable name

Tags: puppet, definition, hosts, hiera

We're using a puppet module to create our hosts entries and it's getting rather large. At the moment we have this

```
host { hiera('server1-hostname'):
ip           => hiera('server1-ip-host'),
host_aliases => 'server1',
}
```

and we have that once per server. We've also got a dev and production environment with slightly different numbers of servers and it's all getting a bit messy.

To simplify it, I'm trying this

```
define hosts::addhost () {
host { hiera("${title}-hostname"):
ip           => hiera("${title}-ip-host"),
host_aliases => $title,
}
}
```

Then in the class,

```
$hostlist = server1, server2

addhost {$hostlist: }
```

but that gives me various errors, such as

Syntax error at ':'; expected '}'

Is this possible? Is it just a matter of punctuation or does it require a totally different approach?

Comment: That theoreticall may work with `$hostlist = [ server1, server2, ... ]` (mind the `[]`s) but yes, there is a better approach. Answer coming up.

Answer (score 1):

It would be less hassle to solve this using [exported resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html).

Each server exports its own host entry, relying on facts such as `$::hostname`

```
@@host { "$::fqdn": ip => $::ipaddress_eth0, host_aliases => $::hostname, tag => "server-list" }
```

And also imorts all those resources from all (other) machines

```
Host<<| tag == "server-list" |>>
```

You can of course use Hiera to make it possible to override the values, e.g. export a specific IP address if `facter` picks the wrong one.

```
@@host { "$::fqdn": 
  ip => hiera('hosts-ip-address', $::ipaddress_eth0),
  host_aliases => $::hostname,
  tag => "server-list"
}
```

---

If you **insist** to have your complete data in Hiera, you may wish to consider the following structure

```
hosts:
  "server1-hostname":
    ip: "a.b.c.d"
    host_aliases: server1
  "server2-hostname":
    ...
```

and in the manifest simply

```
create_resources('host', hiera('hosts'))
```

But this is redundant information, seeing as facter can gather all of those for you (see top).